# Filtering array of objects using includes() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

I am trying to do a filter using `contains`. but not works. any one figureout the issue here.

```
const nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => {
  var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return targetArray.filter(function(eachObj) {
    return filterKeys.some(function(eachKey) {
      return eachObj[eachKey].includes(filters[eachKey]);
    });
  });
};

let filter1 = {Id: "24", Name: "Api Gateway"};
let products = [
  {
    "Id": 100024,
    "Name": "Api Gateway UpdateXX",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "B, Mohamedarif (Cognizant)",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-21-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100026,
    "Name": "Chennai became cold very soon!!",
    "Description": "stridfgdfgng",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100031,
    "Name": "Soma Banerjee",
    "Description": "Updated for Testing2",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100032,
    "Name": "Soma Banerjee",
    "Description": "Soma Banerjee",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100033,
    "Name": "Update Same Data Contact",
    "Description": "Update Same Data Contact",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100034,
    "Name": "New",
    "Description": "New Des",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100039,
    "Name": "100001 New111",
    "Description": "100001 New",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100041,
    "Name": "3 way entry",
    "Description": "3 way entry",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100042,
    "Name": "3 way entry1",
    "Description": "3 way entry",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100043,
    "Name": "ghgjhlk",
    "Description": "sdfsfs",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100044,
    "Name": "ghgjhlk",
    "Description": "sdfsfs",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100045,
    "Name": "Azure New",
    "Description": "Azure New",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100047,
    "Name": "2 way",
    "Description": "2 way",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100049,
    "Name": "C2-new",
    "Description": "C2-new",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100050,
    "Name": "C0001-new",
    "Description": "C00012-new",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100051,
    "Name": "Common Add",
    "Description": "Common Add",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100053,
    "Name": "Mama",
    "Description": "Mama",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100054,
    "Name": "New title",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100055,
    "Name": "CTS",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100056,
    "Name": "New course added",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100057,
    "Name": "Chennai 2020",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100058,
    "Name": "updated Course",
    "Description": "Updated Course",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100059,
    "Name": "New Coursegfdgdfg",
    "Description": "New Course",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100061,
    "Name": "New Cosmos",
    "Description": "Cosmos",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100062,
    "Name": "New Cosmos2222",
    "Description": "Cosmos222",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100063,
    "Name": "New Cosmosooooo",
    "Description": "Cosmoooooo",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100064,
    "Name": "New Cosmo123",
    "Description": "Cosmo123",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100066,
    "Name": "New dfsfsfsd",
    "Description": "Cosmosdfsfsfds123",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100068,
    "Name": "Using good",
    "Description": "strisdfsfsdfng",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100077,
    "Name": "Nadu Nadu",
    "Description": "NaduNadu",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100078,
    "Name": "Course 0013 for Albanian literature",
    "Description": "Course 0012 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100079,
    "Name": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100080,
    "Name": "Course 0003 for Albanian literature",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100081,
    "Name": "a-z",
    "Description": "a-z",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100082,
    "Name": "Course 0004 dipa",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100083,
    "Name": "Update",
    "Description": "Up",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100084,
    "Name": "fsdfsfsfs",
    "Description": "ssdfsdfsftrisdfsdfng",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100086,
    "Name": "fsdfsfsfs",
    "Description": "ssdfsdfsftrisdfsdfng",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100087,
    "Name": "dsdsdfsfsdfs",
    "Description": "strdfsdfsdfsfsding",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100088,
    "Name": "dsdsdfsfsdfs",
    "Description": "strdfsdfsdfsfsding",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100089,
    "Name": "dsdsdfsfsdfs",
    "Description": "strdfsdfsdfsfsding",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100090,
    "Name": "dsdsdfsfsdfs",
    "Description": "strdfsdfsdfsfsding",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100091,
    "Name": "100001",
    "Description": "st100001ring",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100092,
    "Name": "100001",
    "Description": "st100001ring",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100093,
    "Name": "fdgdfdgdgdfgdf",
    "Description": "st1000dsfgddfgdg01ring",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100095,
    "Name": "testservice",
    "Description": "LogicAppVS",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 100096,
    "Name": "TestingLogicApp",
    "Description": "VisualSTudio",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  }
]

console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter1));//getting error.
```

looking the result:

```
{
    "Id": 100024,
    "Name": "Api Gateway UpdateXX",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "B, Mohamedarif (Cognizant)",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-21-17T06:35:20.107Z"
  }
```

thanks in advance.

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d54gvs6z/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the following error in console:

> eachObj[eachKey].includes is not a function

This error is appearing because one of the values in each object is of type `Number` in your array. The method used in code i.e [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is available for `String` type and won't work on type `Number` and will throw above error.

To fix this you need to convert values of type `Number` to string using [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method available on `Number.ptototype` before using `.includes()`:

```js
let filter = {Id: "24", Name: "Api Gateway"};
let data = [{
    "Id": 100024,
    "Name": "Api Gateway UpdateXX",
    "Description": "Course 0002 for Albanian literature",
    "CreatedBy": "B, Mohamedarif (Cognizant)",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-21-17T06:35:20.107Z"
}, {
    "Id": 100026,
    "Name": "Chennai became cold very soon!!",
    "Description": "stridfgdfgng",
    "CreatedBy": "Script",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-04-17T06:35:20.107Z"
}];

let resultBy = (targetArr, filterObj) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(filterObj);
  
  return targetArr.filter(
    o => keys.every(key => o[key].toString().includes(filterObj[key]))
  );
};

console.log(resultBy(data, filter));
```